# Table structure for Scheduling App in SQL DB

Tags: sql, database-design, calendar, relational-database, database-schema

I'm working on a database to hold information for an on-call schedule.  Currently I have a structure that looks about like this:

```
Table - Person: (key)ID, LName, FName, Phone, Email
Table - PersonTeam: (from Person)ID, (from Team)ID
Table - Team: (key)ID, TeamName
Table - Calendar: (key dateTime)dt, year, month, day, etc...
Table - Schedule: (from Calendar)dt, (id of Person)OnCall_NY, (id of Person)OnCall_MA, (id of Person)OnCall_CA
```

My question is: With the **Schedule** table, should I *leave it* structured as is, where the dt is a unique key, or should I *rearrange it* so that dt is non-unique and the table looks like this:

```
Table - Schedule: (from Calendar)dt, (from Team)ID, (from Person)ID
```

and have multiple entries for each day, **OR** would it make sense to just use:

```
Table - Schedule: (from Calendar)dt, (from PersonTeam)KeyID - [make a key ID on each of the person/team pairings]
```

A team will always have someone on call, but a person can be on call for more than one team at a time (if they are on multiple teams).

If a completely different setup would work better let me know too!

Thanks for any help! I apologize if my question is unclear.  I'm learning fast but nevertheless still fairly new to using SQL daily, so I want to make sure I'm using best practices when I learn so I don't develop bad habits.

Comment: I'd suggest edit your question title.

Comment: Yeah, I just did.  That first title was mad confusing and I didn't even realize it.

Comment: (Please consider the following a suggestion, not a criticism.) If a table represents an entity, it is often seems most natural to call it by the entity name (whether to use singular or plural is *highly* debatable, so I'm saying nothing on that head), like `Person`. When another table is essentially a many-to-many relationship between two entities, it is often convenient to call it using the two entities' names. So, if you like, consider if it would work for you better if you called the `TeamIndex` table just `Team`, and the `Teams` one, `TeamPerson` (or, perhaps, `PersonTeam`).

Comment: Good to know.  I'll edit my question to clarify, and change my table names in my plan.  Still trying to find out the best ways to make my data readable :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view, the answer may depend on whether the number of teams is fixed *and* fairly small. Of course, whether the *names* of the teams are fixed or not, may also matter, but that would probably have more to do with column naming.

More specifically, my view is this:

If the business requirement is to always have a small and fixed number of people (say, three) on call, then it may well be more convenient to allocate three columns in `Schedule`, one for every team to hold the ID of the appointed person, i.e. like your current structure:

```
dt   OnCall_NY  OnCall_MA  OnCall_CA
---  ---------  ---------  ---------
```

with `dt` as the primary key.

If the number of teams (in the `Team` table) is fixed too, you could include teams' names/designators in the column names like you are doing now, but if the number of teams is more than three and it's just the number of teams *in `Schedule`* that is limited to three, then you could just use names like `OnCallID1`, `OnCallID2`, `OnCallID3`.

But even if that requirement is fixed, it may only turn out fixed *today*, and tomorrow your boss says, "We no longer work with a fixed number of teams (on call)", or "We need to extend the number of teams supported to four, and we may need to extend it further in the future". So, a more universal approach would be the one you are considering switching to in your question, that is

```
dt   Team  Person
---  ----  ------
```

where the primary key would now be `dt, Team`.

That way you could easily extend/reduce the number of people on call on the database level without having to change anything in the schema.

---

**UPDATE**

I forgot to address your third option in my original answer (sorry). Here goes.

Your first option (the one actually implemented at the moment) seems to imply that every team can be presented by (no more than) one person only. If you assign surrogate IDs to the Person/Team pairs and use those keys in `Schedule` instead of separate IDs for `Person` and `Team`, you will probably be unable to enforce the mentioned "one person per team in Schedule" requirement (or, at least, that might prove somewhat troublesome) at the database level, while, using separate keys, it would be just enough to set `Team` to be part of a composite key `(dt, Team)` and you are done, no more than one team per day now.

Also, you may have difficulties letting a person *change* the team over time if their presence in the team was fixated in this way, i.e. with a `Schedule` reference to the Person/Team pair. You would probably have to change the Team reference in the `PersonTeam` table, which would result in misrepresentation of historical info: when looking at the people on call back on certain day, the person's Team shown would be the one they belong to *now*, not the one they did then.

Using separate IDs for people and teams in `Schedule`, on the other hand, would allow you to let people change teams freely, *provided* you do **not** make `(Schedule.Team, Schedule.Person)` a reference to `(PersonTeam.Team, PersonTeam.Person)`, of course.

Answer (score 2):

- The current version, one column per team, is probably not a good idea. Since you're representing teams as a table (and not as an enum or equivalent), it means you expect to add/remove teams over time. That would force you to add/remove columns to the table, which is always a much larger task than adding/removing a few rows.
- The 2nd option is the usual solution to a problem like this. A safe choice. You can always define an additional foreign key constraint from Schedule(teamID, personID) to PersonTeam to ensure you don't mistakenly assign schedule duty to a person not belonging to the team.
- The 3rd option is pretty much equivalent to the 2nd, only you're swapping a composite natural key for PersonTeam for a surrogate simple key. Since the two components of said composite key are already surrogate, there is no advantage (in terms of immutability, etc.) to adding this additional one. Plus it would turn a very simple N-M relationship (PersonTeam) which most DB managers / ORMs will handle nicely into a more complex object which will need management on its own.

By Occam's razor, I'd do away with the additional surrogate key and use your 2nd option.

Comment: Your answer, being more complete, reminded me that I forgot to address the OP's third option, thanks.